# What's the difference between ContentType and MimeType?

Tags: python, django, content-type, mime-types

As far as I know, they are absolute equal. However, browsing some django docs, I've
found this piece of code:

`HttpResponse.__init__(content='', mimetype=None, status=200, content_type='text/html')`

which surprise me the two getting along each other. The official docs was able to solve the issue in a practical manner:

> content_type is an alias for mimetype.
> Historically, this parameter was only
> called mimetype, but since this is
> actually the value included in the
> HTTP Content-Type header, it can also
> include the character set encoding,
> which makes it more than just a MIME
> type specification. If mimetype is
> specified (not None), that value is
> used. Otherwise, content_type is used.
> If neither is given, the
> DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE setting is used.

However, I don't find it elucidating enough. Why we use 2 different naming for (almost the same) thing? Is "Content-Type" just a name used in browser requests, and with very little use outside it?

What's the main difference between the each one, and when is right to call something `mimetype` as opposed to `content-type` ? Am I being petty and a grammar nazi?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

> Why we use 2 different naming for
>   (almost the same) thing? Is
>   "Content-Type" just a name used in
>   browser requests, and with very little
>   use outside it?
>
> What's the main difference between the
>   each one, and when is right to call
>   something mimetype as opposed to
>   content-type ? Am i being pitty and
>   grammar nazi?

The reason isn't only backward compatibility, and I'm afraid the usually excellent Django documentation is a bit hand-wavy about it. [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) (it's really worth reading at least the Wikipedia entry) has its origin in extending internet mail, and specifically SMTP. From there, the MIME and MIME-inspired extension design has found its way into a lot of other protocols (such as HTTP here), and is still being used when new kinds of metadata or data need to be transmitted in an existing protocol. There are dozens of RFCs that discuss MIME used for a plethora of purposes.

Specifically, `Content-Type:` is one among several MIME headers. "Mimetype" does indeed sound obsolete, but a reference to MIME itself isn't. Call that part backward-compatibility, if you will.

[BTW, this is purely a terminology problem which has nothing whatsoever to do with grammar. Filing every usage question under "grammar" is a pet peeve of mine. Grrrr.]

Answer (score 78):

I've always viewed contentType to be a superset of mimeType.  The only difference being the optional character set encoding.  If the contentType does not include an optional character set encoding then it is identical to a mimeType.  Otherwise, the mimeType is the data prior to the character set encoding sequence.

E.G. `text/html; charset=UTF-8`

`text/html` is the mimeType
`;` is the additional parameters indicator
`charset=UTF-8` is the character set encoding parameter

E.G. `application/msword`

`application/msword` is the mimeType
It cannot have a character set encoding as it describes a well formed `octet-stream` not comprising characters directly.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Setting response mime_type (not content_type) does not override charset and it stays as UTF-8.

Comment: Sometimes simply called "media type", the MIME type is as you say the type of the media. In certain specifications we'll see the term "parsable MIME type", which includes use of the properties in the `Content-Type` header. Syntax of `Content-Type` can be found here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2045#section-5.1

Comment: Yet, in my view, mime-type is a very narrow term limiting itself to mail, while content-type is is plain English for "the type of the content". So, in my view `text/html` is a content-type as well, even if people tend to call that a MIME. Also, the newer name, `media-type`, is even fuzzier, since media is 100 different things. BBC is a media! A DVD is a media! And one would argue that a stream of data is not "media", but a "medium".

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know the details see ticket [3526](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3526).

Quote:

> Added content_type as an alias for
>   mimetype to the HttpResponse
>   constructor. It's a slightly more
>   accurate name. Based on a patch from
>   Simon Willison. Fully backwards
>   compatible.

Answer (score 0):

> Why we use 2 different naming for (almost the same) thing?

Backwards compatibility, based on your quote from the documentation.

Comment: Thats ok, i've understand the pratical reason for adding that on django. However, the core of the question is why *everyone* uses the two words so mixed, and if there is really an difference after all.