# What's the difference between mediatype, contenttype and mimetype?

Tags: http, mime-types, content-type

Is there a difference between *mimetype*, *contenttype* and *mediatype*? (Java's JAX-RS [MediaType](http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/jax-rs/1.0/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html)).

From the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) i gathered that it's only a content-type in the context of e.g. HTTP requests as a field in a request's header: So are these just synonyms or are there any actual semantic differences between the different terms?

Comment: Related, but not duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3452381/320399

Answer (score 115, accepted):

*(Internet) Media Type* is the proper technical term.

*Content-Type* is the name of the HTTP header field used to specify the media type.

*MIME Type* is the [former name for Media Type](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).

Comment: `Content-Type` is not a header specific to http protocol.

Answer (score 13):

### What is MIME Specification:

Concept of [MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions) originally was developed for organizing the structure of contents of the messages transferred over SMTP protocol. However, it's adopted in other communication protocols, such as HTTP.
So Mime, is a specification!  which describes how to show the structure, format and nature of some kind of data, such as a file, or body of an email, etc.

### What is Content-Type

Mime, has several `header-field`s, which are used within protocols taking advantage of this specification. One of these header fields is `Content-Type`. Hence, `Content-Type` is not specific to HTTP protocol. A value that can be assigned to this header, is sometimes called a content type too.
There are other headers too, used for specifying the encoding of the message, or how to message should be displayed (should it be downloaded to shown or not) etc.

### What is a Media Type?

Media type, formerly called mime type, is just a string. AS mentioned in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/MIME_type)

> It (mime type) serves the same purpose as filename extensions traditionally do on Windows

A media type, consists of a `type` (such as `video`) and a `subtype` (such as `3gpp`). `video/3gpp` is an example of media types. The list of registered media types can be seen [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#video). In HTTP and SMTP protocols, the value of the content-type header must be a media type!

---

#### one final point:

We are not always sending just a single image file, or just some text. Sometimes our message consists of multiple parts. Not only that, but also these parts may have a nested structure. MIME is capable of showing how the parts are nested. Actually these parts can be arranged in a tree structure.
If the message has multiple parts, each part has its own `Content-Type`.
media type of any non-leaf node in the tree should have `multipart` type. Its `subtype` can have various values based on the leaves.

Answer (score 12):

*Content-Type* is an HTTP message header and its value is (generally) a *MIME Type*.

JAX-RS *MediaType* seems to be a Java rewrite for common *MIME Types*.