# Is there a difference between MIME and content type?

Tags: http, smtp, mime, smime, rfc822

While using the f12 tools on ie, when I request a web page, the response header has a content type. Can this also be called MIME type? Or is there a difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference of ContentType and MimeType](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452381/whats-the-difference-of-contenttype-and-mimetype)

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate.  That question is about parameters for some Python code.

Answer (score 12):

**Strictly speaking** MIME and content type are two different things.  MIME is a set of standards that was written to extend the capabilities of email messages and has since been applied more broadly to internet content and HTTP.  Content type is a header used both in email messages and HTTP.

**Practically**, however, content type and MIME type are used interchangeably.

**To answer your question**:  In your context, there is no difference.

Answer (score 4):

"Content-Type" is the name of the HTTP header field. The proper technical term for the field value is "(Internet) Media Type" (it used to be "MIME type", but that's not correct anymore since HTTP != MIME).

Answer (score 0):

Content-Type is a HTTP message header key and its value is (generally) a MIME Type. 
Possible duplicate [What's the difference between mediatype, contenttype and mimetype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258108/whats-the-difference-between-mediatype-contenttype-and-mimetype/9277778)