# Content Type vs MIME Type

Tags: operating-system, mime-types, content-type

Can someone explain to me what's the difference between Content-Type and the  MIME Type? I can't find a clear answer on the net.

If Content-Type usually used inside the Browser. 
And MIME type is used by the os?

Answer (score 4):

In `Content-Type=text/plain`, **Content-Type** is a *MIME header*, **text/plain** is *MIME Type*.

Here are more MIME Headers (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526943(v=exchg.10).aspx):

```
MIME-Version
Content-Type
Content-Transfer-Encoding
Content-ID
Content-Description
Content-Disposition
```

Here are more MIME Types (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types. ):

```
text/plain
text/html
image/jpeg
image/png
audio/mpeg
audio/ogg
audio/*
video/mp4
```

More, you can specify an encoding for Content-Type

```
text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 3):

The Content-Type indicates the media type, where media types are defined as MIME types.

[Content Type in RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5)

> The "Content-Type" header field indicates the media type of the associated representation: [...]
> Content-Type = media-type

[Media Type in RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.1)

> HTTP uses Internet media types [RFC2046] in the Content-Type
> (Section 3.1.1.5) and Accept (Section 5.3.2) header fields in order
> to provide open and extensible data typing and type negotiation.

Where RFC 2046 specifies MIME Types.

Comment: I still don't get it, can you give an example. thanks!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3452833/8089107) may clarify it a bit. As far as i understand, `Content-Type` is a MIME header whose value is a mime type. If you send a HTTP request to get an image for example, your response headers contain a header `content-type` with the value `image/png`. The value is the MIME-type.

Answer (score 0):

**MIME (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions)**

MIME was originally designed to solve problems encountered in moving messages between different electronic mail systems.

**Content-type**

Header value defined in a HTTP response, the browser can open the file with the proper extension/plugin.

Example:Content-type: image/jpeg

This format is inspired form MIME format.

Content-type: main_mime_type(image)/mime_subtype(jpeg)

or HTTP adopted it to describe and label its own multimedia content.

Outside from question: MIME sniffing:-is used by some web browsers, in an attempt to help web sites which do not correctly signal the MIME type of web content display.