# How to save to disk a file of unknown content type, when receiving it as a binary stream in a string. (All my attempts corrupt the file)

Tags: javascript, blob

I receive a string from an API that is a binary stream and a filename, here is an example (Shortened for brevity).

```
{ filename: '002-000017.pdf' body: '%PDF-1.7\n\n4 0 obj\n(Identity)\nendobj\n5 0 obj\n(Adobe)\nendobj\n8 0 obj\n<<\n/Filter /FlateDecode\n/Length 181864\n/Length1 542744\n/Type /Stream\n>>\nstream\nx��}\t`�������}dw����~��\t9 @H6'\t�9 e.t.c ' }
```

Other files simply have \u001c\u0004N�v�$$\u0010$�\u0000

In the above example it is a PDF file, but I dont know what content type the file will be, it could be a .docx, .txt or even no file extension. Also the name will not always have an extension. I take this file and convert it to blob, that I attach to and click an anchor.

I have tried specifying no type, 'application/unknown' and 'application/octet-stream'. I even tried hardcoding it to 'application/pdf' for the above sample, just to see if that would work. In every scenario the pdf is blank. (Or unreadable with other file types, docx for example just crashes out when opening with word).

The exception is .txt, any .txt files work perfectly.

I have confirmed the string is convertable manually and readable, I did this using PowerShell without issue. The issue is im doing something wrong in my web side javascript code. What am I missing here?

Code:

```
const { filename } = response
const blob = new Blob([response.body])
const blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
// Using React Ref to handle the anchor.
downloadAnchor!.current!.href = blobURL;
downloadAnchor!.current!.download = 'filename';
downloadAnchor!.current!.click();
```

Comment: You need to map the [mime type (vs ContentType)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452381/whats-the-difference-of-contenttype-and-mimetype) of the request to a file extension. You'll need a table of associations [like this](https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db/blob/master/db.json).  Or a library like [mime-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types) Also, please don't be the person that accepts .exe's from the internet and blindly writes them to disk with an .exe extension.

Comment: Great, thanks, makes sense. I see what the issue is now.